# Additional menu items and view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I saw an awesome tutorial on slide-out navigation menus. I am struggling to have individual navigation menu items to take me to specific view controllers. What should I be doing? Here is the link to the tutorial http://www.appdesignvault.com/custom-transition-slide-out-navigation/